# Hiding a p tag if a list in not present in page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check for the existence of a particular div.class and if its present, then hide a -p- element in a parent level.

So in my code below, I want to say: If ul class element 'dfwp-list' does not exist in this script, then dont show p class element 'linksectionHeading'.

(The code is used multiple places in my page, some have the UL list element "dfwp-column" and others dont. so i dont want the heading to show where there is no list)

```
<div class="linksHolder">
  <p class="linksectionHeading">Most popular items   
  </p>
      <div>    
        <div class="slm-layout-main slwpmarker">                         
          <div class="dfwp-column">
             <ul class="dfwp-list">
               <li>item1</li>
               <li>item2</li>
               <li>item3</li>
             </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried a number of techniques (like the one below) but it either removes all iterations of my -p- tag or doesnt work at all:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.linkSectionHeading').hide();
          if ($('.slwpmarker').has('div.dfwp-column'))
            {
            $(".linkSectionHeading").show();
            }   
});
```

please advice

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/has/  Step one, check the api for the method you are using.  `has()` returns a filtered list, which is a jQuery object.  Object in javascript are truthy.  You can put `.length` on the end of it and it would be true if any of them match.  However, I want to stress my first point.  Always check the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that your class in the HTML has a lowercase `s` which should be corrected to `linkSectionHeading` in order for the JS to select it correctly.

That said, to solve the issue in your logic you need to loop through all the `p` elements then check if they have a related `.dfwp-column` element and hide/show them appropriately. You can use DOM traversal and the `toggle()` method to do that. Try this, note the middle HTML structure has the `p` removed:

```js
$('.linkSectionHeading').each(function() {
  var $dfwpColumn = $(this).closest('.linksHolder').find('div.dfwp-column');
  $(this).toggle($dfwpColumn.length > 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="linksHolder">
  <p class="linkSectionHeading">Most popular items</p>
  <div>
    <div class="slm-layout-main slwpmarker">
      <div class="dfwp-column">
        <ul class="dfwp-list">
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item2</li>
          <li>item3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="linksHolder">
  <p class="linkSectionHeading">Most popular items</p>
  <div>
    <div class="slm-layout-main slwpmarker"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="linksHolder">
  <p class="linkSectionHeading">Most popular items</p>
  <div>
    <div class="slm-layout-main slwpmarker">
      <div class="dfwp-column">
        <ul class="dfwp-list">
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item2</li>
          <li>item3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the correction Rory. That sorted it. thanx

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by @Taplar try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.linkSectionHeading').hide();
      if ($('.slwpmarker').has('div.dfwp-column').length){
        $(".linkSectionHeading").show();
      }   
});
```